# What is c++ equivalent of JNDI?

Tags: c++, binding, naming, jndi

Is there anything equivalent to JNDI in C++?

I am not just looking ldap related libraries. I am interested to know the equivalent API's/Libraries available in C++. Common API for look-up, where implementation can handle against DNS, LDAP, Registry, FileSystem, DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the closest thing to JNDI in the C++ world is perhaps [ADSI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772170(v=VS.85).aspx)/Windows. While it provides a generic lookup interface that is mainly used to access directories of various kinds, i have seen it being used to look-up and read several other kinds of data sources. You would write an ADSI provider for DB, etc.